# Как вывести символ троеточие через диалоговое окно с помощью JS?

Tags: javascript, вывод, символы

Есть символ "троеточие" (HTML код &hellip). Пробовал через fromCharCode(2026), но безуспешно

Comment: `alert('…')` - прекрасно выводит. В чем проблема?

Comment: @Darth  "..." это уже как три символа, а есть троеточие как просто один символ, вот его HTML код &hellip;

Comment: попробуйте скопировать из моего комментария одну точку отдельно…

Comment: @Darth это тоже вариант, но как вывести троеточие зная HTML код этого символа или надо знать его кодировку в Unicode и потом вывести?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы неправильно посмотрели код символа.

```js
alert(
'…'.charCodeAt(0) // 8230
+' '+
String.fromCharCode(8230) //"…"
)
```

Comment: емае, значит я взял Юникод, вместо HTML-кода, все перепутал, премного благодарен!